# Should questions ask for softwarerec whose answers are about tutorial be edited to reflect the new tone?

Tags: discussion, editing, questions, answers

[What word processing tools that can work with complicate text boxing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/102442/26474)

This question initially asks for software-recommendation. But one and a half answers give tutorial for doing the task in Word. Should I edit the question to reflect this direction? What about the other half and the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the question as it is.

You asked for a software recommendation and you received a recommendation of Word. The fact that you initially thought Word wasn't suitable is almost besides the point. Both current answers talk about alternatives as well as explaining how it could be achieved in Word so changing the direction of your question would at best make reading those answers confusing.

Editing for clarity is encouraged, you shouldn't edit a question in a way that changes its meaning though—especially once you've had answers and comments<sup>*</sup>. If your edit would invalidate any of the answers in any way, it's too substantial and shouldn't be done.

---

*<sup>*</sup> Comments in and of themselves aren't too important, they're meant to be temporary and deleting them isn't an a problem—they are however an indication that someone is spending time trying to understand your question and possibly may be formulating an answer.*